# Fading arrows on imageswitcher

Tags: android, multithreading, imageview, android-asynctask, viewswitcher

I'm creating an application that uses an ImageSwitcher to show some images. I want to show arrows on either side of the screen in addition to a button on the bottom whenever a user has touched the screen or switched images. Just like you'll see when viewing screenshots for an application in Android Market.

So far I've had my activity implement OnGestureListener, and I've created an AsyncTask that fades in, sleeps for 1 seconds then fades out again whenever the ACTION_UP event is triggered. The problem is that I want to remove an arrow if the user flings to another image. There's three images.

Here's an exerpt of my code.

```
@Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
   new FadeInOutButtons().execute();
  }

  return mGesture.onTouchEvent(event);
 }

private void fadeOutAll() {


Animation fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
    MyActivity.this, android.R.anim.fade_out);
  mButtonHolder.startAnimation(fadeOut);
  mButtonHolder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  if (mRightArrow.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
   mRightArrow.startAnimation(fadeOut);
   mRightArrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
  if (mLeftArrow.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
   mLeftArrow.startAnimation(fadeOut);
   mLeftArrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
 }
private class FadeInOutButtons extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
   try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
   }
   return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
   fadeOutAll();
   super.onPostExecute(result);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
   Animation fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
     MyActivity.this, android.R.anim.fade_in);
   mButtonHolder.startAnimation(fadeIn);
   mButtonHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   final int sz = mImages.size();
   if (sz > 1) {
    if (mPosition < sz - 1) {
     mRightArrow.startAnimation(fadeIn);
     mRightArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if (mPosition > 0) {
     mLeftArrow.startAnimation(fadeIn);
     mLeftArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
   }
   super.onPreExecute();
  }
 }
@Override


public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
   float velocityY) {
  final int sz = mImages.size();
  if (sz > 1) {

   if (velocityX < 0 && mPosition < sz - 1) {
    mInactive = mActive;
    mActive = (ImageView) mSwitcher.getNextView();
    mActive.setImageResource(mImages.get(++mPosition));
    mSwitcher.showNext();
   } else if (velocityX > 0 && mPosition > 0) {
    mInactive = mActive;
    mActive = (ImageView) mSwitcher.getNextView();
    mActive.setImageResource(mImages.get(--mPosition));
    mSwitcher.showPrevious();
   }
  }
  mInactive.setImageURI(null);

  return true;
 }
```

Have any of you done anything like this before? How can I make only the left arrow disappear when the third image is focused, and only the right one when the first is... And so on... ? I've been stuck on this for an hour.

Thanks!

Sorry about the formatting.

Comment: I'm not sure of the problem, as it looks like the code in `onPreExecute()` is handling the visibility of your buttons based on the position.  Is this not working properly?  Can you describe the current behaviour of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, don't use an `AsyncTask` if you're not actually doing any background work (sleeping doesn't count as work!). Use a `Handler` attached to the UI thread and `postDelayed()` to it.

**WORKING EXAMPLE OF FADING VIEWS IN AND OUT**

Firstly, your layout main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<ImageSwitcher  
    android:id="@+id/imageSwitcher"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    />

<Button android:id="@+id/prev"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Previous"
    />

<Button android:id="@+id/next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Next"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Yes I'm using buttons rather than imageviews, just to keep the example simple.

Now the fade in and fade out animations:

**fade_in.xml**:

**fade_out.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
       android:fromAlpha="1.0" 
       android:toAlpha="0.0" 
       android:duration="500" 
       android:fillAfter="true"/>
```

Finally, some actual code for your main activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageSwitcher;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ViewFactory, OnTouchListener {

    ImageSwitcher imageSwitcher;
    View prev,next;
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    static final int[] images = {
        R.drawable.pic1,
        R.drawable.pic2,
        R.drawable.pic3
    };
    int currentImageIndex = 0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        imageSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.imageSwitcher);
        imageSwitcher.setFactory(this);
        imageSwitcher.setOnTouchListener(this);
        prev = findViewById(R.id.prev);        
        next = findViewById(R.id.next);        
        setCurrentImage();
        scheduleHideButtons();
    }

    private void setCurrentImage() {
        imageSwitcher.setImageResource(images[currentImageIndex]);
    }

    private void scheduleHideButtons() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(hideButtonsRunnable);
        handler.postDelayed(hideButtonsRunnable, 3000);
    }
    private Runnable hideButtonsRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            fadeButtons(false);
        }       
    };

    private void fadeButtons(final boolean fadeIn) {
        if (fadeIn) {
            scheduleHideButtons();
        }
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, fadeIn?R.anim.fade_in:R.anim.fade_out);
        prev.startAnimation(anim);
        next.startAnimation(anim);
        anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                prev.setVisibility(fadeIn?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
                next.setVisibility(fadeIn?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
            }
            @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }
            @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }             
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View makeView() {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(
            ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (prev.getVisibility()==View.GONE) {
                fadeButtons(true);
            }
            else {
                scheduleHideButtons();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try to explain my problem a little better.

I've got two ImageViews and a LinearLayout with a background and a button in it.

Whenever the user presses the screen, I want the ImageView(s) to fade in, along with the button, and disappear again after a second or two.

If the user presses the screen again, I want the views to postpone the fade_out operation by one more second.

My problem right now is that whenever I press the screen, the views restart the fade_in operation completely, going from alpha 0.0 to alpha 1.0.

Any ideas on how I could do that?

Comment: And how does one add line breaks to comments here?

Comment: I think the easiest thing to do would be to knock up a demo project doing what you describe. I'll do that tonight (i.e. in a few hours from now).

Comment: That'd be great! :) If you need a visual example of what I'm trying to accomplish, check out a random app on Market and click on one of the screenshots. It's pretty much exactly what I'm looking for. Oh, I already said that in the original post.

Comment: Added example code to my answer that includes the main bits of interest... the prev/next buttons don't do anything, but I think you're only interested in fading them in and out in response to touch events and after a timeout.

Comment: Thanks! I get what you meant with the handler now. I'll make this work for me. :) I'm impressed that you took the time to code that.